# trouble returning an array of a structure

Tags: c

I'm a newbie and I have a problem with array of type structure. I don't really know where to specify that the array is a pointer and where to not specify it. So whatever the combination I do with pointers in declaration and in calling of function involving this array of structure, it doesn't compile. Do you have any idea why ?
here is the code in question :

```
typedef struct{
  char letter[7];
} player;

player init_player(){
  player tab[2];

  char letter_player1[4]={' ','a','b','c'};
  char letter_player2[4]={' ','x','y','z'};
  strcpy(tab[1].letter,letter_player1);
  strcpy(tab[2].letter,letter_player2);

  return *tab;
}

void displaying(player tab){
  int position=1;
  printf("%c\n",*tab[1].letter[position]);
}

int main(){
  player tab=init_player(tab);
  displaying(tab);
}
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: `strcpy` wants a nul terminated string: `char letter_player1[]={' ','a','b','c','\0'};` and `tab[2]` doesn' t exists, arrays in c are 0 based. Finally, you are returning a local array whose lifetime ends with the function: UB.

Comment: @DavidRanieri The last part of your comment is wrong. Not the local array but the first element of the local array is returned, so no UB for returning pointers that will become invalid.

Comment: @MikeCAT you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your code is wrong:

```
/* required #include (or function prototypes) are not written */

typedef struct{
  char letter[7];
} player;

player init_player(){ /* the return type is not for returning arrays */
  player tab[2];

  /* no terminating null characters are placed, so cannot be used with strcpy() */
  char letter_player1[4]={' ','a','b','c'};
  char letter_player2[4]={' ','x','y','z'};
  strcpy(tab[1].letter,letter_player1);
  strcpy(tab[2].letter,letter_player2); /* only tab[0] and tab[1] are available, tab[2] is out-of-bounds */

  return *tab; /* not the array but only the first element of the array is returned */
}

void displaying(player tab){ /* the argument type is not for getting arrays */
  int position=1;
  /* even if tab were an array(pointer), dereferencing is done via [] operator, so you don't need * here */
  printf("%c\n",*tab[1].letter[position]);
}

int main(){
  player tab=init_player(tab); /* the variable type is not for dealing with arrays */
  displaying(tab);
}
```

How to fix:

```
/* add #include */
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc(), free() and exit() */
#include <string.h> /* for strcpy() */

typedef struct{
  char letter[7];
} player;

/* change return type to return a pointer */
player* init_player(){
  /* you cannot use non-static local array, so instead dynamically allocate an array here */
  player* tab = malloc(sizeof(*tab) * 2);

  /* add terminating null characters (increase array size, and they will be automatically added) */
  char letter_player1[5]={' ','a','b','c'};
  char letter_player2[5]={' ','x','y','z'};

  if (tab == NULL) exit(1); /* for in case the allocation failed */
  /* use tab[0] and tab[1] instead of tab[1] and tab[2] */
  strcpy(tab[0].letter,letter_player1);
  strcpy(tab[1].letter,letter_player2);

  return tab; /* return the (pointer to the first element of) array */
}

/* change argument type to get a pointer */
void displaying(player* tab){
  int position=1;
  /* remove extra * (indirection operator) */
  printf("%c\n",tab[1].letter[position]);
}

int main(){
  /* change variable type to store a pointer */
  player* tab=init_player(tab);
  displaying(tab);
  free(tab); /* the array is dynamically allocated, so clean-up it */
}
```

You don't need the argument `tab` passed to `init_player()`,
but it is harmless because `init_player()` can accept any arguments and the arguments are not used.

Comment: in function: `main()`,  the statement: `player* tab=init_player(tab);` is not correct.  Because the function: `init_player()` does not take a parameter.

Comment: @MikeCAT Wow thank you for this such comprehensive answer, I wouldn't thought of this many error! is there a way around malloc ? if not I guess it's time to learn haha